# What are the houses in Ilvermony?

Tags: harry-potter

So I was sorted into Horned Serpent in Ilvermony on Pottermore.

What are the other ones?

Comment: @Adamant a different question with the same answer is a dupe?

Comment: In this case, yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other houses are:

- [Thunderbird](https://www.pottermore.com/collection/all-about-thunderbird)

  > Thunderbird house is sometimes considered to represent the soul of a
  >   witch or wizard. It is also said that Thunderbird favours adventurers.
- [Pukwudgie](https://www.pottermore.com/collection/all-about-pukwudgie)

  > Pukwudgie house is sometimes considered to represent the heart of a
  >   witch or wizard. It is also said that Pukwudgie favours healers.
- [Wampus](https://www.pottermore.com/collection/all-about-wampus)

  > Wampus house is sometimes considered to represent the body of a witch
  >   or wizard. It is also said that Wampus favours warriors.

Comment: No link for Wampus?

Comment: @bleh - Actually, it looks like this is a dupe.